# Javascript - 2 submit button in one form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

Hi i have a checkout page where customer can pay with paypal OR stripe. I have only one form with all fields like name,lastname,address etc.

MY QUESTION:

i'm tryng to DISABLE stripe submit button and ENABLE paypal submit button when user clickOn paypal button, but is going always to paypal payment and never to stripe controller! how can i resolve this issue? this is my oder-detail.php

```
<form class="login"  id="paypalForm" method="post" action="{{url('payment')}}" disabled>
<form class="login" id="stripeForm" method="post" action="{{url('paymentStripe')}}">






all fields.... name, lastname, address shipping, phone etc.






// This is the button paypal Submit

<button type="submit" id="paypal" class="paypal" onclick="
this.disabledstripe=true;
this.disabledstripeForm=true;
this.enablepaypalForm=true;
this.form.submit();">
<img src="images/paypal.png" width="200" height="35"/>
</button>

// This is the button stripe Submit

<script
src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
data-key="pk_test_yNuawoy0jUqj1GC14jwcQR5d"
data-amount="{{ $total * 100}}"
data-name="dixard"
data-description="Widget"
data-image="https://s3.amazonaws.com/stripe-uploads/acct_14s03fK9wMx3sd9Bmerchant-icon-1416180891533-icona.jpg"
data-locale="auto"
data-currency="eur"
data-id="stripe">
</script>

</form>
```

Or there is a better way ? I need have 2 differents controller (action) for paypal and stripe.

Comment: Are you using a javascript library like jquery at all?

Comment: no! i'm trying to do it with javascript, there is a library jquery that can help me?